# How can polymorphic deserialisation be used out of the box for appsettings in .net 7?

Tags: configuration, polymorphism, deserialization, .net-7.0, appsettings

Trying to deserialise appsettings.json using polymorphism support in .NET7.

See this appsettings.json, for example:

```
{
    "Logging....,
    "Actions": [
        {
            "$type" : "Extract",
            "Action": "Extract something...",
            "FileName" : "temp.csv"
        },
        {
            "$type" : "Process",
            "Action": "Process something...",
            "SomeProperty" : "abcde"
        }
    ]
}
```

now below is the classes structure:

```
public class BaseAction{
    public string Action {get; set;}
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ExtractAction), typeDiscriminator: "Extract")]
public class ExtractAction : BaseAction {
    public string FileName (get; set;)
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ProcessAction), typeDiscriminator: "Process")]
public class ProcessAction : BaseAction {
    public string SomeProperty (get; set;)
}
```

However when configuration is deserialised in the example below all of the actions are deserialised to BaseAction class and not concrete classes.

```
public sealed class ActionProcessor : IActionProcessor, IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<BaseAction> settings;

    public CustodianFileWatcher([Required] IOptions<List<BaseAction>> settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings.Value;
    }
}
```

How to configure json serialiser to use polymorphism by default?

Many thanks in advance!